# Sensenet: Documents Sharing

Tags: sensenet

I'm trying to list the shared files in dashboard through @sensenet/query. But I didn't find any documentation about that. I also tried using the @sensenet/query but I can't find any proper query for that.Please help

Comment: It is not clear what you are seeking. Documentation about what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SharedWidth` is a reference field on every content in sensenet, that contains the list of users with whom the content is shared. So you can search by this field the same as by other reference field is sensenet queries.

For example if you want to search for the documents that are shared with the current user, add the following to the query:

```
SharedWith:@@CurrentUser@@
```